# Xamarin.forms mixing ContentPage and Android Activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I mix both pages together

I want to do something platform specific (Android) `OnActivityResult` but I use a ContentPage in Xamarin.Forms

How do I know in my .Droid project which `activity` it is?

Lets say I have a page called `CalendarPage : ContentPage`.
Where do I register it in my droid project so I can catch the `ActivityResult` in that Activity(ContentPage)?

I have no clue since I'm new to Xamarin.Forms and learning it.

Comment: Xamarin forms runs on one activity (most likely your main activity), so everything will end up in there.

Comment: Pls make it as an aswhere so i can accept it Thanx again m8 :)

Comment: Can ya check somewhere wich activity is loaded ???

Comment: search for  `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);`, the this is the activity.

Comment: Ill put up an example now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Xamarin forms runs on one activity, which is most like your main activity.

There are two sample projects that show you how to communicate between native and form parts of the code, which can be found here

1. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Forms2Native
2. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Native2Forms

However, to answer your question, you would do something like the following

```
 private const int MyRequestCode = 101;

 //Start activity for result
 var contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick, Android.Provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri);
 context.StartActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, MyRequestCode);
```

and then in your main activity (the activity that initializes your xamarin forms application (using `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);`)

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == MyRequestCode && resultCode == Result.Ok)
    {
    }
}
```